# Problems with variables in facebook-sdk-net

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I get the message in this line, that I use local variable "name", which isnt set.

```
string firstname = name;
```

But I set the variable name in  this line

```
name = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
```

Where is my mistake? And how i can set a value from name to firstname?

```
private void LoadUserInfo()
{
    string name;
    var fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

    fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
    {
        name = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
    });

    string firstname = name;

    fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
}
```

---

```
public void LoadUserInfo()
 {
     using (FacebookDataContext db = new FacebookDataContext(DBConnectionstring))
     {
         FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
         fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
         {
             var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
             var FBName = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
             db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName }); 
             db.SubmitChanges();
         };
         fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
     }
 }
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: using local variable "name", which isnt set.
project isnt compiled
but i need it

Comment: You have an issue understanding how callbacks work.  Code doesn't necessarily execute line after line.  Take a hint from anything that says "async" that it doesn't execute immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line resides within event handler block for `GetCompleted` event. Therefore, it will be executed when the event occurs which is after `fb.GetTaskAsync("me")` called and completed :

```
name = String.Format("{0} {1}", .......);
```

That means, at the moment you tried to use `name` variable it hasn't been set :

```
string firstname = name;
```

I know nothing about what you'll do with `firstname` later on.. the thing is, you need to set `firstname` **after** `name` is set, for example, within the same event handler block :

```
fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
{
    name = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
    string firstname = name;
    ....
});
```

**UPDATE :**

```
 FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
 fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
 {
     var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
     var FBName = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
     using (FacebookDataContext db = new FacebookDataContext(DBConnectionstring))
     {
        db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName }); 
        db.SubmitChanges();
     }
 };
 fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
```

Comment: and Do I have methods to set value of name to firstname?

Comment: I want to write this firstname in localdatabase. But I get error and my app is fall, when I want to make record in DB in fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>{});

Comment: Cannot access a disposed object

Comment: In this 

db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName }); 

. I write new answer

Comment: Yes. Error dissapeared. But after first start app dont works correctly. when i'm debugging after db.SubmitChanges(); nothing occurs. app dont move to next line of code.

But when I start app second time it works correctly

Comment: Problems you're getting so far are unrelated and pretty basic. I'd suggest to learn c# from simple things first... "app dont move to next line" means it's processing current line I suppose